# How do I search a file for a particular line, then comment out or comment in that line?

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash script, and within that script I need to act upon a particular file and when I finished acting upon it carry on with the rest of the script.

I need to scan over a file and when I find a particular configuration line, I need to first comment in one configuration and then move on to comment out another configuration option.

**EDIT**: Wow, my first question and I leave out the most important details! I've edited my question with this concrete example:

I'm trying to edit the file dhcpd.conf, and I'm looking for these lines to comment out:

```
option domain-name "example.org";   
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
```

So they end up looking like this:

```
#option domain-name "example.org";
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org, ns2.example.org;
```

At which point the bash script will continue on and execute a bunch of other instructions.

Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.  :-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please spend a minute reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think the important detail you forget to mention is, how do you know which line you want to comment in and which line you want to comment out? Are you finding the line using a pattern search (say grep?) or do you know the line number? Or is it something entirely else? I don't think this can be answered properly without that tidbit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a better solution, but you can try this for file.

```
$ cat file.txt
option domain-name example.org;
dont touch me 
option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org
dont touch this 

$ sed -i 's/^option domain-name/#option domain-name/' file.txt

$ cat file.txt
#option domain-name example.org;
dont touch me 
#option domain-name-servers ns1.example.org
dont touch this 

$ sed -i 's/^option domain-name/#option domain-name/' file.txt
```

This is a [working DEMO through command line using echo](http://ideone.com/YMCzxF)

Comment: When I try this, it just prints out the whole file and doesn't make the changes:  `sed 's/^"option domain-name "example.org";/#option domain-name "example.org";"/' dhcpd.conf` Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: sed will only print changes to STDOUT, not change the file.
Either redirect the output to a new file, or better:
use sed -i. The -i will actually change the file contents. But BE CAREFUL with the -i when testing and developping your script!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to perform many different instructions over one configuration file you may convert instructions to sed commands and then run `sed -f commands config.file.txt`

You must find the most useful examples of sed usage here: http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt